# Text flows out of containing Div

Tags: php, html, css

I have a forum system in php, but when the posts come out, if they're long, they end up like this,

[image: http://www.clankaos.us/include/images/overflow.png (Don't have high enough rep. to post images)]

```
html,
body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: url(/include/images/dirt.png);
    }

.center-container {
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-right:15%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 10px #a7a7a7, 0 1px 0 #fff;
    padding:0.5em;
    }

.button {
    border-top: 1px solid #002136;
    background: #033e66;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#031826), to(#033e66));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #031826, #033e66);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #031826, #033e66);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #031826, #033e66);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #031826, #033e66);
    padding: 5px 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0px;
        border-radius: 0px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
        -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
        box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
        text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
    color: white;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: Georgia, serif;
        text-decoration: none;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding-bottom:3px;
        margin-right:5px;
    }
.button:hover {
    border-top-color: #28597a;
    background: #28597a;
    color: #ccc;
    }
.button:active {
    border-top-color: #1b435e;
    background: #1b435e;
    }

.sidebar1 {
    margin-top:15px;
    float:left;
    width:13%;
    display:inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 10px #a7a7a7, 0 1px 0 #fff;
    }

.sbutton {
    border-top: 1px solid #002136;
    background: #033e66;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#031826), to(#033e66));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #031826, #033e66);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #031826, #033e66);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #031826, #033e66);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #031826, #033e66);
    padding: 5px 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
        -moz-border-radius: 0px;
        border-radius: 0px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
        -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
        box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
        text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
    color: white;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: Georgia, serif;
        text-decoration: none;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding-bottom:3px;
        display:block;
    }
.sbutton:hover {
    border-top-color: #28597a;
    background: #28597a;
    color: #ccc;
    }
.sbutton:active {
    border-top-color: #1b435e;
    background: #1b435e;
    }
```

is there a CSS rule that I can use to make that wrap to the next line?

EDIT: SOLVED! This actually seems to be a problem with Firefox. Not sure why, but if width is set in firefox, even if it is max-width, it will overflow the box for some reason

Comment: image does not exist?

Comment: post the code.  that link is already broken

Comment: Try avoiding percentages for all your widths and heights. The browser doesn't have a fixed value to calculate relative values from. Most sites use fixed resolutions for the parent (like the body).

Comment: Browser compatibility can be a pain in the nose. I see you've fixed it... GG!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CSS3 text-wrap Property:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-wrap.asp

```
p.test {text-wrap:unrestricted;}
```

Comment: While this may be right, w3schools is a proven unreliable source. It teaches poor code practices and serves only as a reference. (Just a heads up to anybody who reads this answer and doesn't already know)

Comment: I agree with @RUJordan. I bumped into this to.

Comment: be aware also that text-wrap is not really supported in any browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Your link doesn't work so I'm guessing here.

Most likely your div expands outside of the width of the screen, meaning that the content will to.
You could try to set the max-width property of your div to something like 80% (or less) and wrap any text in p-tags.

To be absolutely sure, combine that with superUntitled's answer and set:

```
p.test {word-wrap:break-word; }
```

**EDIT**
I tried your example and it works for me in [this JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/selman555/Ye3UW/)

Try a css reset [like this](http://www.cssreset.com/)

Comment: I tried the css reset. Didn't help. If you want to look at the actual site here: http://www.clankaos.us

Answer (score 0):

yes, the CSS3 word-wrap in combination with the hyphen property

```
p.test {
  word-wrap:break-word;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
}
```

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/

Comment: This does not work, i have tried it.

Comment: @user3534341: You should post your code, so others can give your right solution!!!

Comment: @AT-UID I will edit the answer with the css

Comment: This does not work for me either